# C# nested json object issue

Tags: c#, json

I think my json object is setup incorrectly. Trying to setup a nested json object.

```
 string jsonString = "{\"subsidiary\":\"2\", \"vendor_name\":\"644\", \"bill_no\":\"1\", \"due_date\":\"24/04/2016\", \"item:{\"item :\"38\", \"taxcode\":\"13\", \"rate\":\"140\"}" + file + "\"" + "}";
```

It doesn't get parsed correctly with a sytax error like:    SyntaxError: Expected : found i (null$lib#3)

EDIT: Tried the following but still the same error:

```
Dictionary<string, string> jsonObject = new Dictionary<string, string>(); jsonObject.Add("subsidiary", "2"); jsonObject.Add("vendor_name", "644"); jsonObject.Add("bill_no", "100"); jsonObject.Add("due_date", "24/04/2016"); jsonObject.Add("item", "38"); jsonObject.Add("taxcode", "13"); jsonObject.Add("rate", "100"); string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

string jsonString = "{\"subsidiary\":\"2\", \"vendor_name\":\"644\", \"bill_no\":\"1\", \"due_date\":\"24/04/2016\", \"item\":{\"item\" :\"38\", \"taxcode\":\"13\", \"rate\":\"140\"}, \"file\":\"" + file + "\"" + "}";
```

Comment: Try to correct double-quotations, It seems they are not in correct places.

Comment: What's is `file` variable? Can you add complete json after concatenation of file variable?

Comment: can make clear what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a closing " after `item`.

You have

`\"item:{\"item :\"38\"`

it should be

`\"item\":{\"item :\"38\"`

But why are you building the JSON string manually? Use a library like Newtonsoft.Json and you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Tried this but no luck.  <!-- language: lang-cs -->  Dictionary<string, string> jsonObject = new Dictionary<string, string>(); jsonObject.Add("subsidiary", "2"); jsonObject.Add("vendor_name", "644"); jsonObject.Add("bill_no", "100"); jsonObject.Add("due_date", "24/04/2016"); jsonObject.Add("item", "38"); jsonObject.Add("taxcode", "13"); jsonObject.Add("rate", "100"); string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);--> But how do we say the item is also an object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string jsonString = "{\"subsidiary\":\"2\", \"vendor_name\":\"644\", \"bill_no\":\"1\", \"due_date\":\"24/04/2016\", \"item\":{\"item\" :\"38\", \"taxcode\":\"13\", \"rate\":\"140\"}, \"file\":\"" + file + "\"" + "}";
```

[Demo here...](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=baffc5e5eb5e36fb34e0d50dac8bcbb3)